# Switch between mutiple instance of same activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my android application i want following behavior i have two activities  Home-activity and A. Now i have multiple instances of activity A. I want following flow Home-activity -> A(1) -> home-activity -> A(2) -> home-activity -> A(1) here A(1) and A(2) are two different instances of activity A.

I am able to achieve following flow Homeactivity -> A(1) -> homeactivity -> A(2) -> home-activity but now i don't know how to resume to A(1) instance help me please

Comment: You may totally want to reconsider your use case. In such situations as I understand, most people will be using fragment. Can you elaborate your question with the use case please?

Comment: I agree with the fragment idea. Fragment + view pager mightbe the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "resume" an `Activity`, but you can instantiate another instance of this `Activity` with the `Bundle` of the old `Activity` and you can resume the same state.

Although, I would consider using `Fragments`, instead of using a lot of activities.